# получение значения переменной из .js файла, скачанного при помощи fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

Есть расписание лицея, оно в вебе, информация хранится в .js файле, в переменной 
    `var NIKA = {...};` которая json-объект. Нужно: скачать файл с сервера при помощи fetch api, достать расписание из json-а, далее обработать информацию и вывести в красивую таблицу на react-е.
Проблема в том, что я никак не могу достать json-объект из скачанного файла.

пример файла: http://lyceum.nstu.ru/rasp/nika_data_18122017_212113.js.
Либо если он не доступен, то view-source:http://lyceum.nstu.ru/rasp/schedule.html, 8 строка

Вот то, что пока есть...

```
class Scheduler extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://lyceum.nstu.ru/rasp/nika_data_12122017_154528.js')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((text) => {
        require(text);
        console.log('text: ', text);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
        {this.state.isLoading ? <Text>Loading</Text> : <Text>Complete</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Если хотите помочь отрывками кода, попробуйте запустить его в e<a href="repl.it/languages/react_native" title="repl.it">repl.it</a>

Comment: `//schedule in JSON format` но это не json, так как json не поддерживает конструкцию `var =`

Comment: Я понимаю, однако система расписания написана не мною(
Это все NIKA-soft

Comment: тогда принимайте ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.then((text) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(text1.slice(0, text1.length - 1).split('\n')[4]);
})
```